# ¿Seleccionar de lista desplegable y abrir un iframe sobre la misma pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, iframe

Necesito abrir un frame dentro de una misma pagina jsp al seleccionar una de mis opciones.

```html
Principal.jsp

<script language="JavaScript">
function busqueda() {
location=document.buscar.lista.options[document.buscar.lista.selectedIndex].value;
}

</script>

    <h2><body></h2>
          
      <br><h1>Menu Principal</h1><br><br>
          <form name="buscar">
               <style type="text/css">
  h { text-align: center}
 </style>
<select name="lista" size="1">
<option value="Principal.jsp">Pagina Principal</option>
<option value="TablaPersonas.jsp">Consulta Personas</option>
<option value="TablaDirecciones.jsp">Consulta Direcciones</option>
<option value="TablaAutos.jsp">Consulta Automoviles</option>
          
</select>
                       
<input type="button" value="Aceptar" onClick="busqueda()">

</form>
```

De esta manera, al seleccionar una opción en la parte de abajo mediante un frame, se muestre la pagina seleccionada.

Espero sus comentarios. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si no malinterprete la pregunta, lo que podrías hacer es utilizar `.prop` para cambiar, o seleccionar el iframe que quieres.

Por ejemplo, teniendo 3 archivos, `1.html` ; `2.html` ; `3.html`

Podrías hacer algo así;

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="1.html">
      <p>No Soportado.</p>
    </iframe>

    <select>
      <option value="1.html">Rojo</option>
      <option value="2.html">Verde</option>
      <option value="3.html">Azul</option>
    </select>
```

**JavaScript / JQuery**

```
$('select').on('change',function(){

    $('iframe').prop("src", $(this).val());

});
```

Espero que haya sido lo que necesitabas, saludos!